# Issue using polyline routing result for POI search along route

Tags: here-api

I am trying to use the polyline string output of a v8 API route request as input for the compressedRoute parameter of a follow-up browse places request, but get a format error. Here is an example:

query:

> https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=&transportMode=car&origin=52.5308,13.3847&destination=52.5323,13.3789&return=polyline

response contains the compressed polyline:

```
...
"polyline": "BGwynmkDu39wZvBtF3InfvHrdvHvboGzF0FnGoGvHsOvR8L3NkSnVoGjIsEzFgFvHkDrJwHrJoVvb0ezoBjInV3N_iBzJ_Z",
...
```

Using this in a places query like:

> https://places.sit.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/browse?apiKey=&compressedRoute=BGwynmkDu39wZvBtF3InfvHrdvHvboGzF0FnGoGvHsOvR8L3NkSnVoGjIsEzFgFvHkDrJwHrJoVvb0ezoBjInV3N_iBzJ_Z;w=500&cat=petrol-station&callback=

results in the following error:

```
({
    "status": 400,
    "message": "'compressedRoute' parameter is incorrectly formatted: requirement failed: Latitude must be between -90.0 and 90.0, got: 525.30983",
    "incidentId": "38e52b93-6198-479f-a52b-936198579fd8"
});
```

Are polyline and compressedRoute incompatible or might there be a bug?

Comment: I would say they are not compatible. Can you please share documentation link about the `compressedRoute` parameter in places api?

Comment: Docu for compressedRoute in places is here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics_api/resource-browse.html
It uses "HERE polyline encoding". The "polyline" attribute in the routing call returns the route in "flexible polyline encoding" according to the docu in https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html

Comment: Documentation says, this product is `IN MAINTENANCE`, so I would not use it. Compressed polyline is definitely not compatible with flexible polyline.

Comment: Ok. Tomas, thanks a lot for pointing that out. Since the whole "places" API is marked is in maintenance, do you know if there will be any replacement product in the future? Or will the "places" functionality be discontinued?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding documentation on https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/location-contexts.html#location-contexts__here-polyline-encoding
the Places API supports "HERE polyline encoding" that is not the same format as "Flexible Polyline encoding" utilized in Routing API v8 https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline  also are both above not compatible.

---

The new Geocoding and Search API v7 is not supporting the parameters like route, compressedRoute at this moment but will be available later in next releases and will support "Flexible Polyline encoding".